# Is there a "this" reference in R Functions?

Tags: r

Is there a "this" reference in R that allows me to write

```
envir1 <- new.env()
assign("x", 4, envir=envir1)

test <- function(env1) {
    environment(this) <- env1
    return(x + 5)
} 

test(envir1)
```

instead of:

```
envir1 <- new.env()
assign("x", 4, envir=envir1)

test2 <- function() {
    return(x+1)
}

test <- function(env1) {
    environment(test2) <- env1
    return(test2())
}

test(envir1)
```

Comment: there's no need to end each statement with a semicolon. This is R, not C ;)

Comment: But why are you doing this?  Messing with scoping rules is normally an indication that you're trying to do something that is better approached in another way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

how about

```
test <- function(env1) {
    with(env1, {
        return(x + 5);
        })
}
```